# Shopify Order form Ajax loops twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, shopify

I have a Ajax order form on a product page. When you click the `#submit-table` button it will display a drop down menu showing the updated cart information, including updated quantities and prices together with the products that have just been added.

This is an image of my problem (only the green correct item should be showing up):

[image]

This is my code so far but its firing twice thus duplicating products, whats going wrong with it?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#submit-table").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //array for Variant Titles
    var toAdd = new Array();
  var qty;

    for(i=0; i < length; i++){
        toAdd.push({
            variant_id: $("#variant-"+i).val(),
            quantity_id: $("#quantity-"+i).val() || 0
        });
    }

    function moveAlong(){
        if (toAdd.length) {
            var request = toAdd.shift();
            var tempId= request.variant_id;
            var tempQty = request.quantity_id;
            var params = {
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/cart/add.js',
                data: 'quantity='+tempQty+'&id='+tempId,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(line_item) {

          jQuery.getJSON('/cart.js', function(cart, variant, item, line_item) {
            $('nav .customer-wrap ul li.basket span').text(cart.item_count);
            $( '<li class="c-1"><a href="{{ item.url }}" title="View product">  <div class="qc-thumb"><img src="{{ item.product.featured_image.src | product_img_url: 'thumbnail' }}" alt="{{ item.title }}" class="wk-variant-image" /></div>  <div class="qc-details"><p>{{ product.title }}</p>  <p>Qty:' + tempQty + '</p></div></a></li>' ).prependTo( ".basket-quick-view" );
          });

          console.log("success!");
          setTimeout(function () {
            $('nav .customer-wrap ul li.basket ul.basket-quick-view').removeClass('variant-added');
          }, 3000);

          moveAlong();

                },
                error: function() {
                    console.log("fail");
                    moveAlong();
                }
            };
            $.ajax(params);
        }
        else {
            //document.location.href = '/cart';
        }
    };

  jQuery.getJSON('/cart.js', function(cart, variant) {
    $('nav .customer-wrap ul li.basket span').addClass('product-added');
    $('li.empty').hide();
    $('nav .customer-wrap ul li.basket ul.basket-quick-view').addClass('variant-added');
  });

    moveAlong();
});
});
```

Comment: Is it not because you are making the `GET` request twice in your code?

Comment: does element with id submit-table has a child with click event handler?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are calling the `moveAlong()` method again in your `success()` handler of the ajax call to `cart/add.js`

```
success: function(line_item) {

          jQuery.getJSON('/cart.js', function(cart, variant, item, line_item) {
            $('nav .customer-wrap ul li.basket span').text(cart.item_count);
            $( '<li>Removed for clarity </li>' ).prependTo(".basket-quick-view" );
          });

          console.log("success!");
          setTimeout(function () {
            $('nav .customer-wrap ul li.basket ul.basket-quick-view')
                                                       .removeClass('variant-added');
          }, 3000);

          moveAlong();  // Calling it again.

 }
```

Also i would recommend moving out the definition of `moveAlong` method outside of the submit button click event. You may define it out side of the `click` event scope and call the moveAlong() method from the click event. Something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#submit-table").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
       postCartData();
   });
});
function postCartData()
{
   //create the data to send and do call to cart/add
   $.ajax( "cart/add.php" )
  .done(function(response) {
     console.log(response);
     alert( "success" );
     getCartDataAndDisplay();
  })
  .fail(function() {
     alert( "error" );
  });

}
function getCartDataAndDisplay()
{
  //get the cart data and display
  jQuery.getJSON('/cart.js',function(res){
    console.log(res);
     //parse the response and build the UI
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm unsure if I've interpreted your code correctly but I get a 400 bad request when trying to add to the cart now, here's the Pastebin code where I've tried to combine your solution with what I need, could you take a look and see where I'm going wrong? http://pastebin.com/4nNwM0eS

Comment: you are still making one ajax call inside another ajax call !

Comment: Forgive me but I don't know a lot about ajax. What should I be doing?

Comment: Use the code i posted and make the necessary changes (data, url etc) and it should do it

Comment: I thought I had done that but I clearly have got something mixed up. Are you able to help? I'd seriously owe you one!

Answer (score 0):

Simply get ride of moveAlong() you have inside moveAlong function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#submit-table").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //array for Variant Titles
    var toAdd = new Array();
  var qty;

    for(i=0; i < length; i++){
        toAdd.push({
            variant_id: $("#variant-"+i).val(),
            quantity_id: $("#quantity-"+i).val() || 0
        });
    }

    function moveAlong(){
        if (toAdd.length) {
            var request = toAdd.shift();
            var tempId= request.variant_id;
            var tempQty = request.quantity_id;
            var params = {
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/cart/add.js',
                data: 'quantity='+tempQty+'&id='+tempId,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(line_item) {

          jQuery.getJSON('/cart.js', function(cart, variant, item, line_item) {
            $('nav .customer-wrap ul li.basket span').text(cart.item_count);
            $( '<li class="c-1"><a href="{{ item.url }}" title="View product">  <div class="qc-thumb"><img src="{{ item.product.featured_image.src | product_img_url: 'thumbnail' }}" alt="{{ item.title }}" class="wk-variant-image" /></div>  <div class="qc-details"><p>{{ product.title }}</p>  <p>Qty:' + tempQty + '</p></div></a></li>' ).prependTo( ".basket-quick-view" );
          });

          console.log("success!");
          setTimeout(function () {
            $('nav .customer-wrap ul li.basket ul.basket-quick-view').removeClass('variant-added');
          }, 3000);

          //moveAlong(); get ride of this

                },
                error: function() {
                    console.log("fail");
                    moveAlong();
                }
            };
            $.ajax(params);
        }
        else {
            //document.location.href = '/cart';
        }
    };

  jQuery.getJSON('/cart.js', function(cart, variant) {
    $('nav .customer-wrap ul li.basket span').addClass('product-added');
    $('li.empty').hide();
    $('nav .customer-wrap ul li.basket ul.basket-quick-view').addClass('variant-added');
  });

    moveAlong();
});
});
```

Comment: After replacing my code with yours it appears as though 1 product gets added correctly, however if I go and add another product from another page  ajax fires and it looks as if it has been added, however if I go to the actual cart page it just displays the first product only not the additional products that I added afterwards

Comment: review your code in cart/add.js. Ajax succes doesn't mean it succeed to save to db or whatever operation, it's simply means your code did not throw an error

Comment: I can't do that as its a Shopify asset and thus cannot be changed. They have provided their API though: https://docs.shopify.com/support/your-website/themes/can-i-use-ajax-api